# JS - How to select and line-through the items in html list by pressing on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just starting to learn JS and collided with a specific task that i dont understand how to solve.

Suppose we have a page that has a list, and there is a button with which I can supplement this list with new cases.
 The problem that I encountered:
 I need to implement a function in a certain way that will change the style of the selected line from the list of all existing and added elements.

For example, if our list - "a list of things that we have to do", i need to make so that the user can press the "Done" button, and select the desired line. After the selection the selected line gets a line-through.

```js
function addItemToTheList() {
  var newItem = document.createElement("li");
  var input = document.getElementById("Input");
  newItem.innerHTML = input.value;
  input.value = "";
  document.getElementById("todo").appendChild(newItem);
}
```

```css
#todo {
  font-family: Arial;
}

#todo .done {
  color:gray;
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> How can user change added and predefined elements in the list?</title>
  </head>
<pre>
<input type = "text" id = "Input" maxlength = "42" size = "42" placeholder = " Add a task here">  <input 
type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = "addItemToTheList()">

</pre>
 <hr align = "left" width = "378">
  <body>
    <div id = "todoList">
     <ol id = "todo">
        <li class = "done"> Watch all seasons of "Game of Thrones"</li>
        <li class = "done"> Write a book</li>
        <li class = "undone"> Learn "JS"</li>
      </ol> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Would anybody be willing to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're saying, the user clicks a button, to change the strikethroughs of the list, clicks an item, and when he clicks done, that given item is given a strikethrough, or has one removed, depending on the situation?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I think OP is saying click "Done" and then click the item you wish to strike out. Upon clicking an item after clicking "Done" the list item is restyled with a strike-through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create another function, add a button to each of the li items and add an on click function to each button to change the class to done.

Here is a jsfiddle link where i've begun the work required. It isn't fully functional but what would you learn from me doing everything :)

https://jsfiddle.net/nu6b00o0/

```
    (function(){
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for(i = 0; i <= buttons.length -1; i++){
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    doOrUndoItem();
}, false);
if(buttons[i].parentNode.className == 'done'){
buttons[i].className = 'btn-success';
} else {
buttons[i].className = 'btn-warning';
}
}
}());
```

Feel free to ask any more questions

Tom

Answer (score 3):

You have to add, first, a `click` event on each undone tasks.
Then when you create a task just add another `click`event.

Then you just have to click on an undone tasks to change his state.

Hope this is what you want :

```js
function addItemToTheList() {
  var newItem = document.createElement("li");
  var input = document.getElementById("Input");
  newItem.innerHTML = input.value;
  input.value = "";
  document.getElementById("todo").appendChild(newItem);
  
  // Add click listener
  newItem.addEventListener('click', done);
}

function done() {
  this.className = "done";
  this.removeEventListener('click',done);
}

// Initialize all listener for current undone tasks
function init() {
  var undoneItems = document.getElementsByClassName('undone');
  for(var i = 0; i < undoneItems.length; i++){
    undoneItems[i].addEventListener('click', done);  
  }
}
```

```css
#todo {
  font-family: Arial;
}

#todo .done {
  color:gray;
  text-decoration:line-through;
}

#todo .undone {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> How can user change added and predefined elements in the list?</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <pre>
      <input type = "text" id = "Input" maxlength = "42" size = "42" placeholder = " Add a task here">       <input 
type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = "addItemToTheList()">

    </pre>
    <hr align = "left" width = "378">
    <div id = "todoList">
     <ol id = "todo">
        <li class = "done"> Watch all seasons of "Game of Thrones"</li>
        <li class = "done"> Write a book</li>
        <li class = "undone"> Learn "JS"</li>
      </ol> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First at all thank you! This is the thing i looked for. I didnt get yet how exactly it working but i'm on my way to it.
 Can you tip me how to make the new elements be "undone" by default?
And how to change the "done" elements back to "undone".
 It will help me to understand the whole picture. 
  Thanks again for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```js
//list your pre existing items
var items = document.querySelectorAll("li");

function createListElement(){
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
 ul.appendChild(li);
  //add the function in your new items
 li.addEventListener("click", alterStatus)
  //
 input.value = "";
}

// add/remove class
function alterStatus(){
 this.classList.toggle("done");
}

//set the function to the pre existing items
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 items[i].addEventListener("click", alterStatus);
}
```